# Downgrading from ArcGIS 10 to 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3

Recently I have experienced a few problems with ArcGIS 10, so I switched back to 9.3, thinking that my live will be back to normal ... and it is not.

I am using at the [time tool](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~vmerwade/education/terrain_modeling.zip) made by [Venkatesh Merwade](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~vmerwade/), producing river batymetry with sections - great tool by the way.

When I realized that the tool will not work under 10, I switched back to 9.3, so I could work. And it turns out that now when I try to use it under 9.3 I receive an error HRESULT E_FAIL 
[image]

Would anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Can you translate the polish in the dialog (just the first sentence next to the encircled X) ?

Comment: Roughly it would mean: An unhandled exception occurred in the application component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are trying to use may require newer versions of the ArcGIS ArcObjects libraries on your computer.  Have you applied all available service packs to your 9.3.1 install?

Comment: I'll check that and let you if this worked.

Comment: OK I did check. Tool was intended for 9.2 version, but it worked under 9.3 before my 10.0 installation. I am running now 9.3 evaluation copy (not 9.3.1) with Service pack 1 and couple amended liberaries (memory allocation and compress with concurent editors path). I am running eval. copy as under 10.0 the tool does not work at all and wanted to check if I should get 9.3 version instead purchased 10.0. I do want to check the tool properly before switching licence, though it seems now, that something is not stable. I am running it under Windows 7 (64). Any other thoughts?

Comment: At this point you're probably best contacting Venkatesh directly to ask for help.  The E_FAIL error likely means that an unhandled (or unexpected) COM Exception was thrown - or, an API wasn't used correctly, and that requires close inspection to debug.